# DataGridView rows and columns clearing

Tags: datagridview

I have clear my grid view before assigning new values every time so i m using following code:

```
fpsStep4Results.Rows.Clear();
fpsStep4Results.Columns.Clear();
```

It throws me the following exception:
Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.

```
System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Please let me know how can i fix this issue.

Comment: i am checking n vb.net

Comment: did you use datasource??

Comment: yes i used datasouce. i using c#

Answer (score 1):

You must first null the data source `fpsStep4Results.DataSource = null;`

Comment: still the same exception.

Comment: The answer to this question, might be of help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798825/datagridview-system-invalidoperationexception-cell-is-not-in-a-datagridview. The idea is to clear each element in a for loop at index i, k. Where i and k are rows/columns index

Answer (score 0):

Try like this also

```
 ((DataTable) fpsStep4Results.DataSource).Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Its not allowing me to right it this way,there is no ".rows" property for "datagridview.datasource"